# Laravel orderBy working while doing dd but not in table while fetching

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Into my laravel application while I am fetching data by eager loading order by showing me the correct format of data in dd i.e. the data in DESC format, but while i am compacting data and trying to show it in blade it shows the data in ASC format...

My controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
        
   $data = Rate::with('hospital')->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
   // dd($data );
   return view('admin.rates.index',compact('data'));
}
```

My blade file

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        {{-- <th>No</th> --}}
        <th>Hospital</th>
        <th>Contract Date</th>
        <th class="text-center">Contract Length (weeks)</th>
        <th>Weekly</th>
        <th>Hourly</th>
        <th>Others</th>
        {{-- <th>Status</th> --}}
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php $i=0; ?>
    @foreach ($data as $key => $rate)

    <tr>
        {{-- <td>{{++$i}}</td> --}}
        <td>
            {{ ucwords($rate->hospital->short_name) }} 
        </td>
        <td>
            {{date('m/d/Y',strtotime($rate->contract_date))}}
            
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            {{ $rate->contract_duration}} 
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
            
            {{ ($rate->weekly_rate != '') ? $rate->weekly_rate : '' }} 
             
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
            {{ ($rate->hourly_rate != '') ? $rate->hourly_rate : '' }} 
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
            {{ ($rate->others_rate != '') ? $rate->others_rate : '' }} 
        </td>
        {{-- <td>
            
        </td> --}}
        <td>
            @if ($rate->status=='inactive')
            <a href="javascript:void(0);"  id="status_button_{{$rate->id}}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to change')" class="status_button btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-id="{{$rate->id}}" data-url="/admin/rate_status/{{$rate->id}}"> <i class="fas fa-times"></i></a> 
            @else
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="status_button_{{$rate->id}}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to change')" class="status_button btn btn-sm btn-success" data-id="{{$rate->id}}" data-url="/admin/rate_status/{{$rate->id}}"> <i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>    
            @endif
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{{ route('rate.edit',$rate->id) }}"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete')" href="{{ route('rate.destroy',$rate->id) }}"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>

</table>
```

There is nothing much more in it but why the data are not showing in DESC format is my question??? I am also pasting my dd image below where you can see the first data has the id 8 and the second one id 7 which is totally correct but while fetching id 7 comes first why??

[image]

Comment: Are you sure? Can you show the results. Note that you're printing out the ascendingly incremented `$i`, which won't match the id of your results.

Comment: @aynber i didnt get you? Please say clearly what do you want to say

Comment: How do you know it's not printing in descending order?

Comment: @aynber while i am seeing it in blade file...

Comment: I never heard of such behaviour, maybe you can try `@foreach ($data->sortByDesc('id') as $key => $rate)`.

Comment: @OnkiHara same issue didnot solved

Comment: Hi @BabyBabai are you using datatable???

Comment: @Rstdevelpzz  yes why is there is any issue with it???

Comment: Your rows a sorted with javascript i guess

Comment: @Lk77 you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using datatable it tries to filter or sort the data in nearest alphabetical order if serial number is not in use I saw that you have closed tag for serial no try to open it and check the result. I am quite sure it is due to that... Just try to use `"ordering": false` into your datatable function..

Comment: Wait let me check

Comment: Yes it is working now but what if i dont require the serial no.

Comment: See as you are using datatable i just can suggest you to use `"ordering": false` into your datatable function it will work..

Comment: Glad that it worked please mark my answer.......:)